# MySQL bulk insert from CSV data files

Tags: mysql, csv, shell

I have some CSV data files that I want to import into mySQL. I would like to do the insert in a shell script, so that it can be automated. However, I am a bit weary of having the username and password in clear text in the script

I have the following questions:

1. I am uncomfortable with the idea of a uname/pwd in clear text in the script (is there anyway around this, or am I being too paranoid)?. Maybe I can set up a user with only INSERT privelege for the table to be inserted?
2. The database table (into which the raw data is imported) has a unique key based on the table columns. It is also possible that there may be duplicates in the data that I am trying to import. Rather than mySQL barfing (i.e. the entire insertion fails), I would instead want to be able to tell mySQL to **EITHER**

(a) UPDATE the row with the new data **OR**
(b) IGNORE the duplicate row.

Whichever setting I choose would be for the ENTIRE import and not on a row by row basis. Are there any flags etc I can pass to mysql in order for it to behave like (a) OR (b) above

3. Can anyone suggest a starting point on how to write such a (bourne) shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read about [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html), which is a command-line tool provided with MySQL.  This tool is the fastest way to bulk-load CSV data.

The tool has two [options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_replace), `--replace` and `--ignore` to handle duplicate key conflicts.

Regarding security and avoiding putting the password in plain text in the script, you can also use the `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable or the `.my.cnf` file (make sure that file is mode 400 or 600).  See [End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: Thanks  - BTW, are you sure you are not Prince Edward (Earl of Wessex), masquerading in here as a geek ;)

Comment: LOL!  The jig is up!  Oh well, I guess it's back to my full schedule of royal duties.