# Insert CSV to MySQL using Ubuntu Terminal via shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, csv

Is it possible to insert a CSV file into MySQL using a shell script in Ubuntu?

Here's what I tried :

```
mysql -uroot -proot mysfdb < /home/sf/data.csv
```

But I am given an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

Here's a sample content from the CSV file:

```
showinventory_SST312V8N4615041313_1366009574txt_,800-200002.A0,00007985
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811096/mysql-bulk-insert-from-csv-data-files?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maksym Polshcha's answer is correct but is only missing a few things. Apparently, since it's a local file, I have to declare it as a local file in the mysql command. The final command should be something like this:

```
 mysql -uroot -proot --local_infile=1 3parsfdb -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/logfiles/Bat_res.csv' INTO TABLE Bat_res FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
```

Also I made sure that the `/logfiles` directory and the `Bat_res.csv` are world readable.

Thank you for the great answers.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
mysql -uroot -proot mysfdb -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/sf/data.csv' INTO TABLE mytable"
```

where *mytable* is your table for the data. If you have non-standard field/line separators in your CSV file use *FIELDS TERMINATED BY* and *LINES TERMINATED BY*

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when I enter the command, it returns this error : `ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 1: Can't get stat of /home/sf/data.csv (Errcode:2)`

Comment: The errors means that data file in not accessible in `/home/sf/data.csv`

Comment: I am getting error : `ERROR 29 (HY000) at line 1: File '/var/www/html/random_data_Sheet_2.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)
` but file exist on that pathh and it is accessible. What could be the issue?

Comment: @Asmita It must be accessible by a user who owns mysqld process.

Answer (score 1):

**I used this and it worked.**

```
Login in mysql using `mysql -uroot -ppassword --local-infile`
```

Then in terminal:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '.csv path' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Ubuntu Terminal and just run the following command

```
# mysql -u admin -p --local_infile=1 DATABASE_NAME -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'students.csv' INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '\"'"
```

Here,

- DATABASE_NAME = The name of your database
- students.csv  = The CSV file directory, that you want to upload in the database
- TABLE_NAME    = in which table you want to upload your data
- admin         = Database user name

After run this command system asked for the password of the admin user.

Write the password and Enjoy.