# How to send datatable as a parameter to mysql store procedure through asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, mysql

How to send datatable as a parameter to mysql store procedure through asp.net code.
if any solution is there, can anyone please tell me. Its urgent

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You could write it to a .csv and use `LOAD DATA INFILE`
- [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Else you you have to loop through the `datatable` and insert one by one row.

References

1. [Best way to Bulk Insert from a C# DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022531/best-way-to-bulk-insert-from-a-c-sharp-datatable)

Comment: hi, can we send datatable as a parameter to mysql storeprocedure.if possible can you please tell me how to do this.

Comment: No it can't be done in `mysql`. It is possible in `sql-server`.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the data set and for each data row call a stored procedure passing parameters for one data row. If you don't want that, then there are other import facilities (bulk import) like http://brockangelo.com/2009/04/27/how-to-bulk-import-into-a-mysql-database or [MySQL bulk insert from CSV data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811096/mysql-bulk-insert-from-csv-data-files).

Comment: hi, can we send datatable as a parameter to mysql storeprocedure, if possible can you please tell me how to do this